# Creating an authoring instance

Tags: content-deployment, topology

We have a single production farm for our SharePoint 2010 server, behind our firewall and only accessible via the intranet. Is it possible to add an authoring server to our topology? Departmental editors would change content and jobs would push content periodically to production.

Here's what we have in mind: We want to set up a new server ("IntranetAuthor") and do a content deployment from production to that system. Then we'd have users do their changes only on that system with automated jobs to push content to production from InranetAuthor.

From what we know of content deployment, it's safe to push from production to IntranetAuthor to populate it; but pushing from IntranetAuthor to production can be a problem. Is this true? How do people set up an authoring instance after they've already launched a production system and had users editing content on it?

Thanks.